# How to enforce lang="ts" in script tags with an ESLint rule in Vue

Tags: typescript, vue.js, eslint, lint

I'm looking for a way to enforce that everyone working on our code base use TypeScript for Single File Components.
All the components use TypeScript, so disabling JavaScript is also an option.

I thought that this could be done with an ESLint rule, but I can’t find it.

Comment: Although this isn't currently a feature of `eslint-plugin-vue`, [it has been suggested](https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue/issues/1458).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This feature is now available in `eslint-plugin-vue`. Use the `vue/block-lang` rule.

```json
// .eslintrc.json
{
  "vue/block-lang": ["error",
    {
      "script": {
        "lang": "ts"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/block-lang.html#vue-block-lang